# RadixSort that reads strings from a file and sorts in descending order from ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, radix-sort

I'm working on a program that utilizes RadixSort to read in words
from a file and sort in ascending order using an algorithm given to me by my professor (with a requirement that for this RadixSort to work as expected, all entries must be words and all words must be the same length). I've written my RadixSort class:

EDIT: Please ignore the comments within the initializeWords method. They're there for later testing.

```
public class RadixSort implements RadixSortADT{

private ArrayList<String> lowercaseArray;
private ArrayList<LinkedQueue<String>> arrayQueues;
private String results;


public RadixSort(){

}

public RadixSort(ArrayList<String> w) {
    lowercaseArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayQueues = new ArrayList<>();
    initializeList();
    initializeWords(w);
}

public void initializeList() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
           arrayQueues.add(new LinkedQueue<String>());
    }
}

public void initializeWords(ArrayList<String> w) {
    // Get size of first word and check length and if it is a character.
    // Test all 26 letters of the alphabet.
    for(int i = 0; i < w.size(); i++){
        lowercaseArray.add(w.get(i).toLowerCase());
    }
}

public void sort() {
    int item = 0;
    for(int i = lowercaseArray.get(0).length()-1; i>=0; i--){
        for(int j = 0; j < lowercaseArray.size(); j++){
            char character = lowercaseArray.get(j).charAt(i);
            arrayQueues.get(character-97).enqueue(lowercaseArray.get(j));
        }
        item = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < arrayQueues.size(); k++){
            while(!arrayQueues.isEmpty()){
                lowercaseArray.get(item++).equals(arrayQueues.get(k).dequeue());
            }
        }
    }

}

public String toString(){

    for(String words: lowercaseArray){
        results += " " + words + " ";
    }
    return results;
}

}
```

And for further reference, the driver, also provided by my professor, looks like this:

```
public class RadixSortDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file to import words");
    String filename = scan.nextLine();
    //String filename = "four.txt";
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    while(inFile.hasNext()) {
        words.add(inFile.nextLine());
    }
    RadixSort r = new RadixSort(words);
    System.out.println("Unsorted List:\n" + r);
    r.sort();
    System.out.println("\n\nSorted List:\n" + r);
}

}
```

But I'm getting two errors:

1. My output looks something like this:

> Unsorted List:
>   null home  crew  xray  atom  yarn  goat  barn  kite  love  rain  soap

Obviously null is not one of my words; the others are correct, though. I've tried changing my toString and testing with a different input file, but I can't figure out why this is happening.

2. The program will not go further, because I get an EmptyCollectionException (as it says, the queue is empty) at this line:

> lowercaseArray.get(item++).equals(arrayQueues.get(k).dequeue());

But I can't figure out why; when I showed my code to my professor, she indicated that the logic was correct, so I expect we've both overlooked something.

Also, I have no idea how to get my code to print in descending order.

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: 1. is because your `toString` appends to the null field `results`. Make it a local variable and initialise it to the empty string: `String results = "";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set()` to update your `lowercaseArray`. `equals` is used to test for equality. There's also a mistake in the `while` loop you're using to repopulate `lowercaseArray`. It should be checking `arrayQueues.get(k).isEmpty()`.

Fixed code:

```
item = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < arrayQueues.size(); k++) {
    while (!arrayQueues.get(k).isEmpty()) {
        lowercaseArray.set(item++, arrayQueues.get(k).dequeue());
    }
}
```

The problem you're having with your `toString` method is that it's appending to the field `results`, which is initially null. You should make it a local variable and initialise it to the empty string:

```
public String toString() {
    String results = "";
    for (String words : lowercaseArray) {
        results += " " + words + " ";
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Would lowercaseArray.set(item++, arrayQueues.get(k).dequeue) work, since it's an ArrayList of LinkedQueues?

Comment: Sorry, I tested this against the `java.util.Queue` interface (I'm not sure what your `LinkedQueue` looks like; I assume it's from your course work). In `java.util.Queue` the `remove` method removes and returns the head of the queue. I've updated the answer to use the `dequeue` call.